# How to define the value of big M in optimization task, Gurobipy

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gurobi

I'm trying to implement the big M approach to a simple problem but I'm struggling a lot to define the values of big M in the model's constraints.

Thing turn out that if I pick a small value as M, the constraints become invalid, while a big value M could help contains the problem but with other equational constraints generate numerical accuracy issues like the following in Gurobipy and finally IIS

```
x[i] <= 0
value(x[i]) = 1.34252346e-07
```

So, Is there a way to test a suitable M value to constrain one's model?
Thx for any help and suggestions

Comment: I usually try to mathematically deduct the smallest value of a big M such that it does not cut off valid solutions. That may require bounds on variables and proper scaling of the model (including using units that make sense). If you don't have good bounds, you can consider using indicator constraints or SOS1 variables.

Comment: It depends on your problem data, it may be the maximum that the variable cannot exceed. If you add a part the formulation, it will be possible to give you more precision.